# ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::rebase error on armv7/iOS8 devices

Tags: ios

Runs fine on arm64/iOS9 devices but am running into the following error with armv7/iOS8:

```
OS Version:          iOS 8.4.1 (12H321)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x01fc4f34
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x1feec520 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::rebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 588
1   dyld                            0x1fee5796 ImageLoader::recursiveRebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 174
2   dyld                            0x1fee5772 ImageLoader::recursiveRebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 138
3   dyld                            0x1fee4d9e ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 186
4   dyld                            0x1fede2e4 dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 204
5   dyld                            0x1fedf2c2 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2362
6   dyld                            0x1fedb222 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 394
7   dyld                            0x1fedb03c _dyld_start + 60
```

Seen some talk regarding this issue here: [Adding several pods increases iOS app launch time by 10+ seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080284/adding-several-pods-increases-ios-app-launch-time-by-10-seconds). But there was no resolution.

Anyone dealt with this issue before?

Full crashlog looks like this:

```
OS Version:          iOS 8.4.1 (12H321)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x01fc4f34
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x1feec520 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::rebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 588
1   dyld                            0x1fee5796 ImageLoader::recursiveRebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 174
2   dyld                            0x1fee5772 ImageLoader::recursiveRebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 138
3   dyld                            0x1fee4d9e ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 186
4   dyld                            0x1fede2e4 dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 204
5   dyld                            0x1fedf2c2 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2362
6   dyld                            0x1fedb222 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 394
7   dyld                            0x1fedb03c _dyld_start + 60

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x6ef13640    r1: 0x01fc4f34      r2: 0x01fb4000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0xffffffff      r6: 0x03d41290      r7: 0x00842758
    r8: 0x02458000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000002     r11: 0x1fefeac0
    ip: 0x01fc4f34    sp: 0x00842680      lr: 0x03d412c8      pc: 0x1feec520
  cpsr: 0x40000030

Binary Images:
0x68000 - 0x41ffff TestApp armv7  <893f19267a8b35aaa09779fa72c6e577> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/23A56AE6-E50C-437D-B9BC-31142940E281/TestApp.app/TestApp
0x844000 - 0x1457fff TestAppSDK armv7  <b7454046d0d13122b97805b01f93d4d0> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/23A56AE6-E50C-437D-B9BC-31142940E281/TestApp.app/Frameworks/TestAppSDK.framework/TestAppSDK
0x1fb4000 - 0x2457fff TestAppVideoController armv7  <59eaa49a37983a2e80e7fccca5b365d3> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/23A56AE6-E50C-437D-B9BC-31142940E281/TestApp.app/Frameworks/TestAppMintConaxVideoController.framework/TestAppMintConaxVideoController
0x3dc0000 - 0x3dc7fff TestAppAnalyticsCommon armv7  <359fdc4e16fd3f8a968e0fa30b3eb101> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/23A56AE6-E50C-437D-B9BC-31142940E281/TestApp.app/Frameworks/TestAppAnalyticsCommon.framework/TestAppAnalyticsCommon
0x1feda000 - 0x1fefdfff dyld armv7  <5784795b4bd43222b72f4fd81972bcfa> /usr/lib/dyld
0x237d2000 - 0x2393ffff AVFoundation armv7  <8551959d83fe36d98c9a5f681a3fe6c6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x23940000 - 0x2399ffff libAVFAudio.dylib armv7  <624faeb8ce1a3d398031377f971aeca3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x239da000 - 0x239dafff Accelerate armv7  <2625f05f4ff435d9ac0994555c14bb1a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x239eb000 - 0x23c04fff vImage armv7  <99a9ccd2fd113e9394cf8ecf6c327064> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x23c05000 - 0x23ce2fff libBLAS.dylib armv7  <133c977bb0983e2f9ebb57d9b8d3f1b8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x23ce3000 - 0x23fa6fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <a25513161f193fe7879eed04bcf64ad1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x23fa7000 - 0x23fb9fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib armv7  <7ece094b2baa36f8b6a5cb90ce2e46da> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x23fba000 - 0x2402efff libvDSP.dylib armv7  <21a6fbdd74303ecca17d7eee2543a039> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x2402f000 - 0x24040fff libvMisc.dylib armv7  <177a0e102a2d30a0ae5fdad8d9c53926> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x24041000 - 0x24041fff vecLib armv7  <a768aa894c4836338c1f49fe3502e7af> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x24042000 - 0x24069fff Accounts armv7  <8676ea5c77d430a7a97c303c8b54be28> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x2406b000 - 0x240d9fff AddressBook armv7  <f04fd59982b83d9b981474eb22003a20> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x240da000 - 0x24202fff AddressBookUI armv7  <4ebacccb0f203381a143f9cd0439333e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x24203000 - 0x24215fff AssetsLibrary armv7  <8ca451a59a9b340db035a43c13d79104> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x24398000 - 0x2460cfff AudioToolbox armv7  <b2b2309c919838f29ee7425c08afc165> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x24778000 - 0x24907fff CFNetwork armv7  <abad3f24833138f59f9dc0fb36c98487> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x24908000 - 0x2498dfff CloudKit armv7  <d876427893043060bdf39f087cc95853> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x2498e000 - 0x249edfff CoreAudio armv7  <c70889845f873b3fa644a1cae18e43b0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x24a09000 - 0x24a26fff CoreBluetooth armv7  <b554f9cb0d073bddaa5014954011cdbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x24a27000 - 0x24c3ffff CoreData armv7  <7e1f283e392535a6a2473ad9acb72976> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x24c40000 - 0x24f73fff CoreFoundation armv7  <27e0318c286c3a39a5bd1c041ae9b9ae> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x24f74000 - 0x2509efff CoreGraphics armv7  <25597ae24fb135f09bce3e241c4f8a13> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x252ef000 - 0x25401fff CoreImage armv7  <fe3d317ef78334b1b7beb5c536c48101> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x25402000 - 0x2545afff CoreLocation armv7  <a1a5ebdd8a073c49b17a76939ca7cd86> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x2548c000 - 0x2552afff CoreMedia armv7  <b53e81ba1d973d9887783164416ec516> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x2552b000 - 0x25609fff CoreMotion armv7  <4a3eebc1173a33179450c9170cb676a0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x2560a000 - 0x25668fff CoreTelephony armv7  <7a3c12828b6b3ba1be07f753355f952b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x25669000 - 0x25736fff CoreText armv7  <2afee4d30dba3bf1b23b9627010d4150> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x25737000 - 0x2574dfff CoreVideo armv7  <7155300fed8b34f3b868dd2a52eb0fe2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x2574e000 - 0x25844fff EventKit armv7  <4e2e642ceb1e312a85578e5fbabf7b5f> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x259bb000 - 0x25bc0fff Foundation armv7  <4a6c050b49d73f499fa2e138c3c0e4a1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x25bed000 - 0x25c0cfff GSS armv7  <c3b98ac8cdbc3a48ae0060658bd2dd1f> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS
0x25cc2000 - 0x25d17fff IOKit armv7  <aef87fa38f0239bbbe4360dd20f5edd6> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x25d18000 - 0x25f61fff ImageIO armv7  <0814012834dd377c8100507312b7b94c> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x25f62000 - 0x262acfff JavaScriptCore armv7  <000cea69d32132d68bfc20c794edbeff> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x264a0000 - 0x265a3fff MapKit armv7  <00cfc3a7c5823df2854f59fda5a3888a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x265a4000 - 0x265acfff MediaAccessibility armv7  <b1e0d6aa64473cb7854b51f04763a2ac> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x265ad000 - 0x267c6fff MediaPlayer armv7  <5ddef080972332809f1ee8e328223062> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x267c7000 - 0x26b26fff MediaToolbox armv7  <fd090b2dccf33587b6ae1f650c4b5b03> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x26b27000 - 0x26be6fff MessageUI armv7  <acd2316077733dbe8985af92beee7953> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x26be7000 - 0x26c56fff Metal armv7  <06af7f0c67433d82910440208f1415dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x26c57000 - 0x26cebfff MobileCoreServices armv7  <ae02603187a63f529fd9d449616e9f0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x2787f000 - 0x27887fff OpenGLES armv7  <518eef6cc79733508b9212d50ea6c6e6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x27889000 - 0x27889fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <f8a600f92e043a279b27face0467123d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x2788a000 - 0x2788cfff libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <d4c2cf3e626b3cb0a142c00f5a8e7ad1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x2788d000 - 0x27890fff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <aa478e0af82132b5a4ccf4a94cb2522d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x27891000 - 0x27899fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <953d0c6cc3dc3f9285f7e910e8278e79> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x2789a000 - 0x278d9fff libGLImage.dylib armv7  <117cb8c632eb3ee0ad5e3ff5c2601fbd> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x27af9000 - 0x27b7afff Photos armv7  <664f75bd292e3e0986e6cf30afb51129> /System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework/Photos
0x27daf000 - 0x27f0ffff QuartzCore armv7  <423d6696f1ac3b0f8cdd1bd3b9facf86> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x27f10000 - 0x27f56fff QuickLook armv7  <373d2ab6be053ae48e8a117809a900f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x28144000 - 0x28191fff Security armv7  <31ad0c48766d3f02bab4175b11e59ce7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x28192000 - 0x28213fff Social armv7  <6bf43167a4e83b6e8e6c22dea70ad789> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
0x2833e000 - 0x2839afff SystemConfiguration armv7  <4057b59c404c37b7adafc0cbf6513935> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x2839d000 - 0x28c4bfff UIKit armv7  <0eecf8deeadb3cc2bc8c12832e2f16c9> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x28c4c000 - 0x28cb3fff VideoToolbox armv7  <fcc7944ffb31313bb22605e5a9f535fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x28cb4000 - 0x28ce2fff WatchKit armv7  <9362310e477c3f7687aeb4914f5592dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/WatchKit.framework/WatchKit
0x28ce3000 - 0x28ecffff WebKit armv7  <b2d77bf95623350581915bcbb680b0ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x291d9000 - 0x291e4fff AOSNotification armv7  <cc028c990af5301e888dd63d16c9ed0b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
0x29342000 - 0x29393fff AccountsDaemon armv7  <6657e57f7d1934fc9cbffb9f374b43c4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsDaemon.framework/AccountsDaemon
0x29394000 - 0x293b6fff AccountsUI armv7  <787da176d56e3859b9c1dc67a0118a2d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsUI.framework/AccountsUI
0x293b7000 - 0x293bbfff AggregateDictionary armv7  <8b49ae4e48f734b49858c3926175d2e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x2955e000 - 0x29561fff AirPlaySupport armv7  <d65d6fd828bb37358fea79fceb783383> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/AirPlaySupport
0x29776000 - 0x297b4fff AppSupport armv7  <dc25189f10f43a6c844d2ef4746a3b67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x297b5000 - 0x29805fff AppleAccount armv7  <14633d273a873616b0368466e0db3ce6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x298f6000 - 0x29934fff AppleJPEG armv7  <87dace913f53351b998fa3e29daa27b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x2993f000 - 0x29951fff ApplePushService armv7  <4643bb99dc2733c1a70fc5257e290e63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x2aff1000 - 0x2aff7fff DataMigration armv7  <50a25e3ce3a23d37b5d7d80ee25ecbf5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x2b00d000 - 0x2b00efff DiagnosticLogCollection armv7  <c1616819b2f33a72b177b86e67dcba1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x2b00f000 - 0x2b029fff DictionaryServices armv7  <255671d19ed63fbdb117a1173585128e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x2b048000 - 0x2b067fff EAP8021X armv7  <ce058c48b35a3d74b7b06ba2092d2511> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x2b16a000 - 0x2b16cfff FTClientServices armv7  <c8dc1a16f4133f79bf73ea38cb5551d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x2b16d000 - 0x2b19cfff FTServices armv7  <aaa0b5421a283abcaa1eec3146118293> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x2b19d000 - 0x2b5c0fff FaceCore armv7  <b5776c59732c3a5c8c1097e3ca084aa3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x2b5e8000 - 0x2b5e8fff FontServices armv7  <1db55cc4be6e3d148a364889202d824e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x2b5e9000 - 0x2b6befff libFontParser.dylib armv7  <4ee8ab7c34783c9ba2043181fd75729b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x2b7b2000 - 0x2b7cefff FrontBoardServices armv7  <2a2604510dee372d9544992e5ce9dd47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x2c2e6000 - 0x2c2fcfff GenerationalStorage armv7  <0fd1673433713a8abe1a5a44b6fd0dc5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x2c2fd000 - 0x2c5bdfff GeoServices armv7  <9e9e8878a5c0331eb6571d7ac623f6b4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x2c5be000 - 0x2c5cefff GraphicsServices armv7  <b851d0aa57043f9886e512ac7f181878> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x2c6ac000 - 0x2c6fbfff Heimdal armv7  <c611ecc51ee033a391b3e032b4d4efa9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Heimdal
0x2c7de000 - 0x2c863fff HomeSharing armv7  <a6bcbe8572dd3e2fac8768f9768bafbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x2c8c5000 - 0x2c924fff IDS armv7  <7618a8529f8131339f483b9899bb1d1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/IDS
0x2c925000 - 0x2c950fff IDSFoundation armv7  <629e2372d5573fffb8b2b03a1f94352d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
0x2cb07000 - 0x2cb6bfff IMFoundation armv7  <676f5ca14de033088841d3aecec3d353> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x2cb73000 - 0x2cb76fff IOAccelerator armv7  <b879abc90dbb39c5834b33600967a917> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x2cb79000 - 0x2cb7ffff IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <ebd64137fa2732eeb45a9eff4aad5ff7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x2cb80000 - 0x2cb85fff IOSurface armv7  <dfaf5c248ad13f7facca062783742fdb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x2cb86000 - 0x2cb87fff IOSurfaceAccelerator armv7  <9dc2544c749c30e388dc584c5ce26933> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x2cc3a000 - 0x2cc40fff IntlPreferences armv7  <76c8e1cb191d31cf9d8256a08c7abb99> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntlPreferences.framework/IntlPreferences
0x2cc41000 - 0x2cc7afff LanguageModeling armv7  <5d13e49348b3354db09409b31177f5fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x2ccb6000 - 0x2ccf3fff MIME armv7  <3f811e5ac63530fabcc3c372bb1cc817> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x2ccf4000 - 0x2cd51fff MMCS armv7  <fa6fa98e98e23bee967d8ca2e261d783> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
0x2cdba000 - 0x2cdc7fff MailServices armv7  <3ade3d102b8c3466b09361439b0ab55b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x2cdfb000 - 0x2ce9dfff ManagedConfiguration armv7  <b0df9569a58a38c1b181a8a7810f4adc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x2ceab000 - 0x2ceacfff Marco armv7  <c028bddaaa5d3326a228903ba2b21bfd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x2cead000 - 0x2cf0efff MediaControlSender armv7  <c90bf28b6f813f6c981444f8a9eb6826> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x2d01d000 - 0x2d032fff MediaRemote armv7  <0c40ec3b9ee83953a1a7eee54918fad9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x2d033000 - 0x2d047fff MediaServices armv7  <acb91c18fdda303cb2b3883ec6fe3725> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaServices.framework/MediaServices
0x2d0a3000 - 0x2d0bbfff MediaStream armv7  <d4a8f88335513a7095266dd306e6f81d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
0x2d125000 - 0x2d203fff Message armv7  <659a2f61e96d35a086cbc370f3b7e7e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x2d209000 - 0x2d20bfff MessageSupport armv7  <e2c27d1de4c739fc88180c33df68f306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x2d21a000 - 0x2d227fff MobileAsset armv7  <67fe97f1c0f73f0da55f6273a4302848> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x2d24f000 - 0x2d258fff MobileBluetooth armv7  <a5cda06417da3ad69bcbc454a0bea1c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x2d274000 - 0x2d27cfff MobileIcons armv7  <787b5e0f2d42321abca4f948f02d38b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x2d27d000 - 0x2d284fff MobileInstallation armv7  <7aa0261405193d708534f23747a3fae1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x2d285000 - 0x2d291fff MobileKeyBag armv7  <3a986b00b55b38e9ada7554b059b652f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x2d2be000 - 0x2d2c1fff MobileSystemServices armv7  <d80584e8070331369e99d93e40f7b483> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x2d2e4000 - 0x2d2f1fff MobileWiFi armv7  <64ad34e7ecdc3a3882dc28a4dacde6ed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x2d33a000 - 0x2d53afff MusicLibrary armv7  <9fead5c7b0eb32b8bf7c919ab5f1d869> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x2d564000 - 0x2d578fff NanoRegistry armv7  <7747b7de832d33248fa9b773b95a7f75> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NanoRegistry.framework/NanoRegistry
0x2d583000 - 0x2d588fff Netrb armv7  <dabfe39f95eb32f1ba59557818aeeeea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x30bc8000 - 0x30beefff WebBookmarks armv7  <58fc6db77b9132fe95088dca37ab1461> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x30c04000 - 0x31783fff WebCore armv7  <0fb7c96fe7f43ddd9fa749e3bb8aa0e5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x31784000 - 0x31842fff WebKitLegacy armv7  <14fccc6a183238e6ac36078d081b7b33> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x319fe000 - 0x31a04fff XPCKit armv7  <214c6b0949a43cd58d5d108f5955156a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCKit.framework/XPCKit
0x31a05000 - 0x31a0dfff XPCObjects armv7  <bcf01dfab5543240b104407542366a52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x31bff000 - 0x31c24fff iCalendar armv7  <9ee78e02934b34eba443d5e499441fd2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x31e18000 - 0x31e56fff iTunesStore armv7  <9ec1b2ffde8537e4add35fda6291b3ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x3269b000 - 0x326a3fff libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <76cbcf3943523557af470c72381a8c92> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x327d5000 - 0x327ebfff libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <539d3a10ddd43fbcb3e09167286986e5> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x32821000 - 0x32924fff libFosl_dynamic.dylib armv7  <fbb5d66ba2ec362f864581915d8a0572> /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
0x3293e000 - 0x32955fff libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <e31c22cd41b1360f9a4c13ecf9c90363> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3297b000 - 0x3297cfff libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <1353dd91fbac387087c75cf8931ce39e> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x329ed000 - 0x32a31fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib armv7  <99517c72776c3e748d87f3cdc0b17176> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x32b41000 - 0x32b63fff libarchive.2.dylib armv7  <7d9ac46ec87d31328258a6f167344d0e> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x32b64000 - 0x32b64fff libassertion_extension.dylib armv7  <7ed2961abb6730bb8eaab6888fcb4b82> /usr/lib/libassertion_extension.dylib
0x32b93000 - 0x32b9ffff libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <189bfe384a453f9ea396c2562f6ef521> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32ba0000 - 0x32ba9fff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <d63e96685df23bf69198b896ff299cf3> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32baa000 - 0x32bf4fff libc++.1.dylib armv7  <85055cf4732f3667abc23ab1493c3703> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x32bf5000 - 0x32c10fff libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f99212723e363c78aac2d3821fa43245> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x32c12000 - 0x32c1ffff libcmph.dylib armv7  <a952fcd587a43645a32c4b0c285c78de> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x32c4f000 - 0x32c68fff libextension.dylib armv7  <62b3fe124db73a7299a52c6dd980aec1> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x32d99000 - 0x32d9cfff libheimdal-asn1.dylib armv7  <0a4c3a3bb4de3500b094742b6dfa6ab7> /usr/lib/libheimdal-asn1.dylib
0x32d9d000 - 0x32e8afff libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <9eb49aab944934509e4a9046e22f8e80> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x32e8b000 - 0x32ff9fff libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <0d4db0af5afe3927917f108551ecb468> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x33006000 - 0x33006fff liblangid.dylib armv7  <20a0c0e6bb983e4b97bf9665f3a8e0ea> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x33007000 - 0x33011fff liblockdown.dylib armv7  <6ca4920bb6b435baa4f4f468bec9f5c1> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x33012000 - 0x33027fff liblzma.5.dylib armv7  <f9468d83c79c3c13924fbe0b67bf5825> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x333a2000 - 0x333b7fff libmis.dylib armv7  <acbfe52af459320c92ef81d57d803e3e> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x333e1000 - 0x335dbfff libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <d8dce7276c203150bdcbd105266b7968> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x336b3000 - 0x336c9fff libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <4dca2e76321e33ad9ba917e43ad72a88> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x336f4000 - 0x337a4fff libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <9eedf01990863eb4a4209fa9bb33270c> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x337f2000 - 0x33819fff libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <e613be21d9fc321e84205dc85c87204b> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3381a000 - 0x33822fff libtzupdate.dylib armv7  <94d3ccb961f03a38a1ccac5bc7de5877> /usr/lib/libtzupdate.dylib
0x33826000 - 0x338dcfff libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <1381f71041d035628a0276827dfd7996> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x338dd000 - 0x338fefff libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <2c075dfeb05732258d1859298a907763> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x338ff000 - 0x3390bfff libz.1.dylib armv7  <433c3df1213f3f2c8b97d2f747c7dcff> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3390c000 - 0x33910fff libcache.dylib armv7  <289d2b8e9fd83e149062521f1890a518> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x33911000 - 0x3391afff libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <a182ac4b579e3a2d95f256a8a1f9e2e4> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3391b000 - 0x3391ffff libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <5136d1a17b22372e969d71ff8f6a5ef2> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x33920000 - 0x33926fff libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <05f098cd548e37348bfaaaa5a18ee4da> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33927000 - 0x33975fff libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <4f8a9b9015823f3a959dfe73f5e22957> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x33976000 - 0x339b3fff libdispatch.dylib armv7  <89da9738c8d7335a81c8c1d297533a99> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x339b4000 - 0x339b5fff libdyld.dylib armv7  <97e40854039630108c6898dadb83a10d> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x339b6000 - 0x339b6fff libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <8cf4f5d2baca35ed8a5f15c4af240d0c> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x339b7000 - 0x339b7fff liblaunch.dylib armv7  <3f9c6ce07fb13ee0a15dbf56f965061c> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x339b8000 - 0x339bbfff libmacho.dylib armv7  <21a119e030f23aec84234e445bc8e1ca> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x339bc000 - 0x339bdfff libremovefile.dylib armv7  <b38c744ff50f3a25b8c29ee79624d6ae> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x339be000 - 0x339cffff libsystem_asl.dylib armv7  <e2aa00ff982433c784b55217febdcec1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x339d0000 - 0x339d0fff libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <b11c0cd1df5038edaa021f6ee35e60c1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x339d1000 - 0x33a33fff libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <1f977c22653936dc99f8ecba1a4673e3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x33a34000 - 0x33a36fff libsystem_configuration.dylib armv7  <9f5b5c4178f73bec863400eef38fb8ac> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x33a37000 - 0x33a38fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib armv7  <34e08e7e53ff3b018a9b58482a2fd6ae> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x33a39000 - 0x33a45fff libsystem_coretls.dylib armv7  <19227fbb451b3c8d8e1c121b9f6e2a01> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x33a46000 - 0x33a4cfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <9729751e11fe32ab86cf7881fc90c7f0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x33a4d000 - 0x33a66fff libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <66ea004683e432c7b62c0d1462d25618> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x33a67000 - 0x33a81fff libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <143e025b6d9a3eeca173eb206b8ca401> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x33a82000 - 0x33aa2fff libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <84ad54e1d9cc3e61a02d8f2b6f29309c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x33aa3000 - 0x33ab5fff libsystem_malloc.dylib armv7  <d9a24ab278d03403b4e3f7a1a14ecf6b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x33ab6000 - 0x33ae4fff libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <e7b6cee8e696332e8d478e98efdd5a17> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x33ae5000 - 0x33aeafff libsystem_networkextension.dylib armv7  <65d0c152ac9632d887363beec9b39f75> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x33aeb000 - 0x33af2fff libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <efe3c04093c6360088c28a19418aeb14> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x33af3000 - 0x33af8fff libsystem_platform.dylib armv7  <87e23da2b47437b2a3189d2c55666309> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x33af9000 - 0x33afffff libsystem_pthread.dylib armv7  <8938d02473573e8ca011ba70f0c8eaf9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x33b00000 - 0x33b02fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <d769f6ca52243740ac340a17e1cf6119> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x33b03000 - 0x33b06fff libsystem_stats.dylib armv7  <4632ee54d68d38a0994ee05a47cf708e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
0x33b07000 - 0x33b0cfff libsystem_trace.dylib armv7  <66a47b2a88933709b4da7836295d2a8d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x33b0d000 - 0x33b0dfff libunwind.dylib armv7  <e52b05cc2ec13f4d9f9307d7c6393ae7> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x33b0e000 - 0x33b29fff libxpc.dylib armv7  <3c761f5ef2fd315b895a4054cae2232e> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this issue was with the linker flags:

```
-read_only_relocs suppress
```