# Wildly different Swift app start times from the same build

Tags: ios, swift, compilation

I have been getting consistently different app launch times from doing "hot" launches on the iOS Simulator (i.e. the simulator is up and running, and I am launch the app). The app is a Swift 3 app making no internet calls, and showing static data.

The largest deviation is the `rebase/binding time`, and here are the recorded times for 10 launches:

```
rebase/binding time:  13.88 milliseconds (13.8%) (100.50 total)
rebase/binding time: 355.57 milliseconds (78.6%) (452.12 total)
rebase/binding time: 338.66 milliseconds (77.7%) (435.72 total)
rebase/binding time:  15.08 milliseconds (20.8%) (72.24 total)
rebase/binding time:  14.04 milliseconds (19.6%) (71.39 total)
rebase/binding time: 342.97 milliseconds (78.1%) (438.68 total)
rebase/binding time:  21.56 milliseconds (27.2%) (79.22 total)
rebase/binding time:  14.99 milliseconds (19.6%) (79.12 total)
rebase/binding time:  15.57 milliseconds (21.2%) (73.19 total)
rebase/binding time: 340.25 milliseconds (78.3%) (434.12 total)
```

From observation, it seems like either a particular element is ran during `rebase/binding`, causing it to balloon, or its not ran at all. This [article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/slow-app-startup-times/) suggests that this process is "fix-ups adjust pointers within an image (rebasing) and set pointers that point to symbols outside the image (binding)", but I actually have no images displayed or even loaded into my app.

Any suggestions or tips about how to achieve more consistent rebase/binding time is much appreciated.

Comment: Even 350 milliseconds is a pretty fast launch time, isn't it?

Comment: It would be nice, but Apple recommends aiming for 400ms: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/slow-app-startup-times/ That and right now this app is at its very beginning stages and does almost nothing.

Comment: You probably have seen this already but this looks like a good link: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080284/adding-several-pods-increases-ios-app-launch-time-by-10-seconds). Maybe testing on a device will give different results than on a simulator? Are you launching with a debugger?

Comment: Indeed I have, and that's a good point.  I may get more consistency on a device. Will report back